# Cannot get reset_input_buffer() function to work at all in Pyserial 3.5. Does anyone have any idea what may be happening?

Tags: python, python-3.7, pyserial, input-buffer

I am trying to simulate a communication protocol where I am following a pattern, so I constantly loop though looking for the same set of characters to reply information. I'm using an RS-232 adapter and the protocol I am simulating is asynchronous and half-duplex where the rx/tx lines are tied together by design and that causes a sort of echo when reading after writing.

That said, I need to be able to clear the input buffer after every write I send out in order to avoid reading what I just wrote. So whenever I use `reset_input_buffer()` it does not clear the last message I sent out. I have tried to fix this using a couple of methods, such as: using `reset_output_buffer()` together with `reset_input_buffer()`, using `reset_input_buffer()` twice, and using `flush()`. None of these methods make any difference, the only other method that works to clear the buffer is closing and immediately opening the port but this causes a delay that messes with the timing as it is critical at certain times.

I'm open to any suggestions, please help!